# Return the second row from a series of table entries

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to generate a report that only returns the second row for a **series** of entries.

When I use limit/offset my return is only one line, as it should be. This is not what I want.

Here is what I have:

```
SELECT HD_TICKET_ID, 
HD_TICKET.CREATED, 
HD_TICKET_CHANGE.TIMESTAMP,
USER.FULL_NAME

FROM `ORG1`.`HD_TICKET_CHANGE`, 
`ORG1`.`USER`, 
`ORG1`.`HD_TICKET`
WHERE (HD_TICKET_ID = HD_TICKET.ID)

AND HD_TICKET_CHANGE.USER_ID = USER.ID 

ORDER BY  HD_TICKET_ID
```

Which returns

```
HD_TICKET_ID,Created,Timestamp,Full_Name
....
31  2008-04-15 17:26:25 2008-04-15 17:26:25 S. Redacted
31  2008-04-15 17:26:25 2008-04-16 11:48:34 C. redacted
31  2008-04-15 17:26:25 2008-04-16 12:18:25 C. redacted
31  2008-04-15 17:26:25 2008-04-17 15:19:34 M. redacted
33  2008-04-17 06:23:27 2008-04-17 08:40:24 A. redacted
33  2008-04-17 06:23:27 2008-04-17 09:18:17 C. redacted
33  2008-04-17 06:23:27 2008-04-17 08:35:41 C. redacted
33  2008-04-17 06:23:27 2008-04-17 08:30:00 C. redacted
33  2008-04-17 06:23:27 2008-04-17 06:23:27 L. redacted
33  2008-04-17 06:23:27 2008-04-17 15:18:55 M. redacted
36  2008-04-17 07:37:20 2008-04-17 11:31:19 M. redacted
36  2008-04-17 07:37:20 2008-04-17 07:37:20 A. redacted
36  2008-04-17 07:37:20 2008-04-17 07:48:58 A. redacted
36  2008-04-17 07:37:20 2008-04-17 07:56:34 A. redacted
36  2008-04-17 07:37:20 2008-04-17 08:04:36 A. redacted
42  2008-04-17 09:11:28 2008-04-17 09:36:14 M. redacted
42  2008-04-17 09:11:28 2008-04-17 09:11:28 S. Redacted
42  2008-04-17 09:11:28 2008-04-23 00:03:20 M. redacted
42  2008-04-17 09:11:28 2008-04-24 13:06:18 S. Redacted
42  2008-04-17 09:11:28 2008-04-24 13:06:31 S. Redacted
....
```

However what I want is only the second line for each of those; so the output should look something like this:

```
....
31  2008-04-15 17:26:25 2008-04-16 11:48:34 C. redacted
33  2008-04-17 06:23:27 2008-04-17 09:18:17 C. redacted
36  2008-04-17 07:37:20 2008-04-17 07:37:20 A. redacted
42  2008-04-17 09:11:28 2008-04-17 09:11:28 S. Redacted
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use session variables, following is sample code

```
 select * from 
      (select @rowid:=@rowid+1 as rowid, 
                id, username from user, 
                (select @rowid:=0)as init) as t 
      where rowid%2=0;
```

as for your purpose, I think you may write your sql as following

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT @rowid:=@rowid+1 as rowid, 
        HD_TICKET_ID, 
        HD_TICKET.CREATED, 
        HD_TICKET_CHANGE.TIMESTAMP,
        USER.FULL_NAME

    FROM `ORG1`.`HD_TICKET_CHANGE`, 
        `ORG1`.`USER`, 
        `ORG1`.`HD_TICKET`,
        (SELECT @rowid:=0 as init) as rowtable
    WHERE (HD_TICKET_ID = HD_TICKET.ID)
        AND HD_TICKET_CHANGE.USER_ID = USER.ID
    ORDER BY  HD_TICKET_ID) as t
WHERE rowid%2=0
```

Hope helps!

Comment: This generates an [Error 1248](http://www.hassmann-software.de/en/mysql-error-code-1248-every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias/) The resolution in link, mentioned, doesn't seem to resolve the issue adding quotes to the t in `ORDER BY  HD_TICKET_ID) as t`

Comment: I have fixed the bug, cause (SELECT @rowid:=0 as init) is a table, it needs a name, so I named it rowtable, you can try the sql now, good luck